# Purchase Order (PO) link to Sales Order (SO) breaks / lost - MYOB Exo Business

Tags: salesforce, myob, jitterbit

I'm using MYOB Exo Business. We have Sales Orders in the system which sync from Salesforce through Jitterbit. Our purchasing team creates a Purchase Order against the Product lines on the SO, which creates a linked PO. However, we have been experiencing breaks in the link. That is the PO and the SO are both still there, but they are no longer connected, which makes it appear like the PO hasn't been created.

This could simply be due to updates in Exo breaking the link, and/or changes in Salesforce that are pushing through to Exo, and then breaking the link.

Has anyone experienced this, or something similar before? There are just so many potential reasons why this could be happening; but it would be good to hear the most likely causes/ideas.

Thanks.